# Adjusting image sizes and padding in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and divided the row in 4:8, In col-4 I am displaying a paragraph while in col-8 i am trying to display a thumbnail carousel of 3 picture in each col, The problem which i am facing is the picture are having some margins specifically on left and right of the carousel, Which i want to remove and secondly i want to display the 3 images of 240*158 (actual) size each in the carousel. Here is my code

Actually i want to have some thing like that[image: Here is the link]

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-8">
        <h1> Current Projects </h1>

  <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" style="background:#CCC">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="fff">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="fff">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="fff">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x20" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
```

CSS

```
img{
max-width:100%;
}
.thumbnails li> .fff .caption 
{ 
background:#fff !important; 
padding:10px
}
ul.thumbnails { 
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
/* Thumbnail Box */
.caption h4 {
color: #444;
}
.caption p {  
color: #999;
}
li { list-style-type:none;}
```

Comment: @Ricky can you share url / jsfiddle

or try to put row class with thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

u need to remove padding and border from thumbnail class

like this

```
.thumbnail{
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

see my updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26541/)